# Mpmovieplayercontroller in iPad - No Video only audio

Tags: ipad, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am developing an iPad app where I am playing the videos stored within the app itself. I am representing the list of videos in a table view. When I select a row, the video 
corresponding to that row plays. But while performing this, sometimes screen goes black , no video is visible but only audio is playing.

I am aware that making the video play in fullscreen mode or using the MPMoviePlayerViewController eliminates this problem. But my requirement is that I don't want to play the movie in fullscreen initially. Please guide me on how this can be achieved.

```
-(void)playMovie {
   MPMoviePlayerController *movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]     initWithContentURL:movieUrl];
   self.moviePalyer = movieController;
   [movieController release];

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePalyerDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object: self.moviePalyer];

 self.moviePalyer.view.frame = CGRectMake(240, 0, 561, 313);
 self.moviePalyer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 [self.moviePalyer prepareToPlay];
 [self.view addSubview: self.moviePalyer.view];
 [self.moviePalyer play];

}
-(void)moviePalyerDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
 [moviePalyer.view removeFromSuperview];
 [moviePalyer stop];
 moviePalyer.initialPlaybackTime = -1.0;

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
              object:moviePalyer];
 [moviePalyer release];
 moviePalyer = nil;
}
```

NOTE: This is on ipad simulator

Comment: How do you declare the moviePlayer property in your header?

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer; @property(nonatomic, retain)MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue. Previously I was creating the MPMoviePlayerController for each of the row selection, and releasing it in the moviedidfinish notification method .But now, instead of creating movieplayercontroller for every row selection, I am reusing the MPMoviePlayerControler object which has been already created.

Following is the Code snippet:

```
-(void)playMovie
{
   if(self.moviePalyer == nil)
   {

    MPMoviePlayerController *movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    self.moviePalyer = movieController;
    [movieController release];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePalyerDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.moviePalyer];

    self.moviePalyer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    self.moviePalyer.view.frame = CGRectMake(240, 0, 561, 313);
    self.moviePalyer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
else 
{
    [self.moviePalyer setContentURL:url];
    [self stopMovie];
}
[self.view addSubview: self.moviePalyer.view];
[self.moviePalyer play];
   }
   -(void)stopMovie
   {
     [self.moviePalyer.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.moviePalyer stop];
self.moviePalyer.initialPlaybackTime = -1.0;
   }
```

I am releasing the moviePlayer object in the dealloc method.

Hope this helps who is having the same issue.